# Haskell How to convert general tree to Data.Tree

Tags: haskell, tree, type-conversion

I have declared my general tree as follows

```
data GeneralTree a = EmptyTree | Node a [GeneralTree a]
```

I have built an instance of this GeneralTree. Now I want to convert it to the Tree type declared in [Data.Tree](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.6.1/html/libraries/base/Data-Tree.html). How do I do it?

I want to write a function with follows type

```
convertTree :: GeneralTree a -> Tree a
```

but I'm having trouble dealing with the empty tree because there is no counterpart for it in Data.Tree definition of Tree.

Comment: What is giving you problems? What have you tried?

Comment: I think it's just `unfoldTree`.

Comment: @hammer: I am unable to deal with the empty tree because there is no counterpart for it in Data.Tree defn of Tree

Comment: you can create a Maybe Tree and use Nothing for empty trees.

Comment: @WillNess: That is an option, but you still have to deal with cases like `Node 42 [EmptyTree, EmptyTree]`. Should you simply discard the inner `EmptyTrees`? Or should that make the whole conversion fail?

Comment: @hammar ahh, didn't think of that! If I had to do something I could just remove all empty trees on conversion. But that depends on what matters more to the OP here - the contents, or the shape.

Comment: @WillNess thank for the hint to use `Maybe` type to manage `EmptyTree` case. I find returning `Tree (Maybe a)` more appropriate than `Maybe (Tree a)`

Comment: Will Ness is right; I think `Tree (Maybe a)` would be annoying, and that `EmptyTree` subtrees are worth deleting unless there's a compelling problem-specific reason to keep them. Returning `Maybe (Tree a)` is a very standard (and safe) approach to dealing with unusable input.

Comment: @AndrewC `Tree (Maybe a)` isn't annoying too much, further we can from `Tree (Maybe a)` go safely to `Tree a` and obtain the desired result. Moreover, the type signature of `unfoldTree` advocate for a use of `Tree (Maybe a)`. On the other hand, I've tried to find a way using `unfoldTreeM` but when an `EmptyTree` is meet the whole Tree is deleted and only `Nothing` is returned, I do no see a reason for this behavior but maybe I've not been able to implement it.

Comment: It is annoying because code that works on Tree (Maybe a) has to deal with Nothing all over the place. unfoldTreeM is the semantic problem, not Maybe (Tree a).

Answer (score 3):

The `Maybe` can only be use at the top level of the tree, due to the definition of `Tree a`. This will only avoid the conversion of 'pure' `EmptyTree`, this sound good as there can't be an equivalent value in the targeted type. Then as said in my first answer the only way to accommodate with later occurrence of `EmptyTree` is to take advantage of the linear recursive nature of list allowing an easy way to skip them.

Finally, for the top node we must wrap the result into a `Maybe` type to avoid conversion of a pure `EmptyTree`. Then, we can reasonably work on the sub-forest without any worry.

This lead to this version, which is easiest to follow.

```
convertGTree :: GeneralTree a -> Maybe (Tree a)
convertGTree EmptyTree             = Nothing
convertGTree (GNode a forestGTree) = Just (Node a forest)
    where 
      forest = buildForest forestGTree
      buildForest :: [GeneralTree a] -> [Tree a]
      buildForest []     = []
      buildForest (x:xs) = case x of  
        GNode n forest -> (Node n (buildForest forest)) : (buildForest xs) 
        _              -> buildForest xs
```

An illustration test,

```
>>> let testGeneralTree = GNode "0" [GNode "1" [GNode "2" [], EmptyTree], GNode "3" [EmptyTree]]
>>> putStrLn . drawTree . fromJust . convertGTree $ testGeneralTree
0
|
+- 1
|  |
|  `- 2
|
`- 3
```

---

#### Using unfoldTree and returning a Tree (Maybe a)

First, avoid the use of Node for your data constructor as it's already in use by Tree data type or you will encounter a name's collision. Which why we've chosen to redefine it like this,

```
data GeneralTree a = EmptyTree | GNode a [GeneralTree a] 
    deriving (Show)
```

You can deal with this `EmptyTree` by the mean of a intermediate `Maybe` type.
To start, I pass by a `buildSafeTree` function which use `unfoldTree` behind the scene.
An helper help to manage the case and return Nothing when you encounter `EmptyTree` value.
When the safe tree is build, we can clean it using `cleanSafeTree`, the trick reside in `cleanForest` which will skip `Nothing` value by case of statement.

The code below,

```
testGeneralTree = GNode "0" [GNode "1" [GNode "2" [], EmptyTree], GNode "3" [EmptyTree]]

convertTree :: GeneralTree a -> Tree a
convertTree = cleanSafeTree . buildSafeTree

buildSafeTree :: GeneralTree a -> Tree (Maybe a)
buildSafeTree = 
  unfoldTree helper 
    where 
      helper :: GeneralTree a -> (Maybe a, [GeneralTree a]) 
      helper EmptyTree       = (Nothing, []) 
      helper (GNode a trees) = (Just a, trees)


cleanSafeTree :: Tree (Maybe a) -> Tree a 
cleanSafeTree tree@(Node (Just root) forest) = 
  Node root (cleanForest forest) 
    where 
      cleanForest :: Forest (Maybe a) -> Forest a
      cleanForest []     = []
      cleanForest (x:xs) = case x of  
        Node Nothing _      -> cleanForest xs
        Node (Just x) trees -> (Node x (cleanForest trees)) : (cleanForest xs)
```

some test,

```
>>> testGeneralTree 
GNode "0" [GNode "1" [GNode "2" [],EmptyTree],GNode "3" [EmptyTree]]

>>> putStrLn . drawTree .  convertTree $ testGeneralTree
0
|
+- 1
|  |
|  `- 2
|
`- 3

>>> putStrLn . drawTree . fmap show . buildSafeTree $ testGeneralTree
Just "0"
|
+- Just "1"
|  |
|  +- Just "2"
|  |
|  `- Nothing
|
`- Just "3"
   |
   `- Nothing
```

Using `unfoldForest` is shorter.

```
convertTrees :: GeneralTree a -> Tree a
convertTrees (GNode a forest) = 
  Node a (cleanForest . unfoldForest helper $ forest) 
    where
      -- build a Forest of Tree (Maybe a) from GeneralTree a
      toTreeMaybe :: GeneralTree a -> (Maybe a, [GeneralTree a])
      toTreeMaybe EmptyTree           = (Nothing, [])
      toTreeMaybe (GNode a subForest) = (Just a , subForest)
      -- Clean the Maybe a, for a Forest of Tree Maybe a
      fromMaybe :: Forest (Maybe a) -> Forest a
      fromMaybe []     = []
      fromMaybe (x:xs) = case x of    
        Node Nothing _     -> cleanForest xs
        Node (Just x) trees -> (Node x (cleanForest trees)) : (cleanForest xs)
```

---

#### A Monadic Version Using UnfoldTreeM to return `Maybe (Tree a)`

A solution using `unfoldTreeMonadic`

```
convertMonadicTrees :: GeneralTree a -> Maybe (Tree a)
convertMonadicTrees = unfoldTreeM helper where 
    helper :: GeneralTree a -> Maybe (a, [GeneralTree a]) 
    helper EmptyTree       = Nothing
    helper (GNode a trees) = Just (a, trees)
```

The main difference, it's returning nothing then if a GeneralTree contain an EmptyTree Value it will be discarded.

```
>>> testGeneralTree2 
GNode 0 [GNode 1 [GNode 2 [],EmptyTree],GNode 3 [EmptyTree]]
>>> convertMonadicTrees testGeneralTree2
Nothing
```

Comment: The unfoldTreeMonadic is broken because it's using Maybe with error propogation semantics: fail on first error. That's a flaw in your code rather than in the data type, because as a subtree, an EmptyTree is empty, not erroneous. Only a whole tree which is empty should be rejected by the conversion.

Comment: @Andrew ok, thank. I think I've got it now. You were right returning a `Maybe (Tree a)`, is definitively the easiest way (I found). I was stuck on sub `EmptyValue` as I didn't see how the list nature of forest will clean these later's value, despite the fact I've notice this trick at the beginning. Anyway, working on this kind of data is really confusion.